# Extract eigenvalues from gm.prcomp

Tags: mathematical-morphology, morphological-analysis

I am used to using plottangentspace from geomorph package. This function has been replaced by gm.prcomp, but I am not able to extract eigenvalues, even if I used the function summary, or summary.gm.prcomp.
If I used summary, I have statistical summary (mean...), and I can't use summary.gm.prcomp (R doesn't find the function)
How can I do to extract my eigenvalues?

Thank you for your help!

Marine

Answer (score 0):

The function 'gm.prcomp' reports the singular value decomposition of the VCV matrix, and you can reconstruct Eigenvalues from there, as the sum singular value decomposition is equivalent to the total variance in the data.

Say 'ProcFit$coords' is our Procrustes-fitted data, then

`PCA<-gm.prcomp(ProcFit$coords) # calculates the PCA`
`PCA$d[1]/sum(PCA$d) # provides the Eigenvalue for the first principal component.`

You can also see the resemblance to Eigenvalues, if you

`plot(PCA$d)`

Or, for example, if you want to build a data frame from all PCs that accumulatively explain at least 80% of the variation:

`PCframe <- function(PCA, CutOff=80) {  # default cutoff of 80%`
`EigenSum<-k<-0`
`repeat {` 
   `k<-k+1`
   `EigenSum<-EigenSum+PCA$d[k]/sum(PCA$d)`
   `if(EigenSum>=CutOff/100) {`
       `break}}`
`PCAframe<-data.frame(PCA$x[,1:k])`
`return(PCAframe)}`